# Will the continuity of functional calculus in another aspect still be ture?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

It is a well known fact that if we have a fixed normal operator $T$ on $B(H)$, $f$ and $g$ are both continuous on $\sigma(T)$, then $||(f-g)(T)||=||f-g||_{\sigma(T)}$. It tells us that functional calculus for a fixed operator is continuous, which means if $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly in $\sigma(T)$, then $f_n(T)\rightarrow f(T)$ in norm.

My question is, if we have a fixed continuous function $f\in C(E)$, a sequence $T_n\rightarrow T$ in norm, where $T$ and $T_n$ are both normal, satisfying that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma(T_n)\cup \sigma(T)\subset E$, do we know that $f(T_n)\rightarrow f(T)$ in norm?

How about the case for Bounded Borel functional calculus?

Comment: Can you prove the result if $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: I can't do that for a polynomial right now, actually I guess the continuity in this sense may not be true in general, but I have no idea how to find a counterexample. I just wonder if we can have some partial result? Like for self adjoint operator or unitary operator?

Comment: Can you prove the result for a single power $f(\lambda)=\lambda^n$?

Comment: The answer is no for Borel calculus and an elementary counter-example can be found with $H$ one dimensional!

Comment: My apology, It should be simple for polynomials.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the continuous functional calculus the result is as you say. This is a typical $\varepsilon/2$-argument. You have that any continuous function is a uniform limit of polynomials, and it is easy to show that for a fixed polynomial $p$ you have $p(T_n)\to p(T)$.

For Borel functions, the answer is no even if you require sot-convergence instead of norm, even in finite-dimension. For this take $e_n=\frac1n\,1$, then $e_n\to0$ in all relevant topologies. If we take $f(t)=1_{(0,1]}$, then $f(e_n)=1$ for all $n$, but $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I do understand the proof for continuous functions.

Comment: Although I have a question about the counterexample for Bounded Borel functions, I think the same counterexample should work for continuous function either? If we consider the same sequence $e_n$ and a continuous function $f(t)=1$ for all $t$. then  $f\in C(\mathbb{C})$ and we have $f(e_n)=1$ since $\sigma(e_n)=1/n$ and $f$ is a constant $1$ in the spectrum?

Comment: Oh, I guess I understand your counterexample right now, Is there a typo here? I guess the function $f$ should be $f(t)=\mathbb{I}_{(0,1/2]}$  instead of $f(t)=\mathbb{I}_{[0,1/2)}$,  and this situation (the sudden change near 0) won't happen in continuous function. Do I understand it right?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, corrected now.